# masking sensitive data from logs using promtail loki grafana stack in kubernetes using helm

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki, promtail

I was trying to mask sensitive data in my logs, like personal information from my application log, using promtail, but I couldn't mask it. I'm using promtail, Loki & Grafana as my monitoring stack.
My application is deployed in GKE, Here is my config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: promtail-config
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: promtail

data:
  promtail.yaml: |
    server:
      http_listen_port: 9080

    clients:
     - url: http://grafana-loki.default.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push

    positions:
      filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: your_log_job
        static_configs:
          - targets:
              - localhost
            labels:
              job: your_log_job_label`

        pipeline_stages:
          - regex:
              expression: "Password: (.*)"
              source: message
              target: __password_masked__

         - labels:
             masked_log: true`
```

And here is my sample log:

```
[INFO] [User: John Doe] [Action: Record Addition] [IP: 123.456.789.123]
[INFO] [Details]
[INFO] [Name: John Doe]
[INFO] [Email: john.doe@email.com]
[INFO] [Educational Institution: XYZ University]
[INFO] [Degree: Bachelor of Science]
[INFO] [Major: Computer Science]
[INFO] [Graduation Date: 2022-05-15]
[INFO] [Note: The user provided explicit consent for data collection during registration on [website/app name]. Data will be retained for a period of [X years] for record-keeping purposes.]
[INFO] [Password: Password]`
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

[`regex`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/regex/) stage is for extraction of data from message into labels.

You need [`replace`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/replace/) stage.

In your case you probably need stage with the following configurations:

```yaml
- replace:
    expression: "Password: (.*)\]"
    replace: "__password_masked__"
```